# How to invoke the appium server and emulator via Java code in windows machine

Tags: java, selenium, appium

**I need to start up the Appium server and emulator through the Java code with Selenium**. When I run the Java program the *startappiumserver* method is working well. When it comes to *startApplication* method *(creation of new remoteWebDriver)* I am getting an error like:

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. *Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.***

**CODE:**

```
package startup;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Startup {

    static RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

    public void startAppiumServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

        CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
        command.addArgument("/c");

        command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node.exe");  
        command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\lib\\appium.js");  
        command.addArgument("--address", false);  
        command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");  
        command.addArgument("--port", false);  
        command.addArgument("4723");  
        command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);  

        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
    }


    public  void stopAppiumServer() throws IOException {  
        CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");  
        command.addArgument("/c");  
        command.addArgument("Taskkill /F /IM node.exe");  

        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
        executor.setExitValue(1);  
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);  

    }

public static  void startApplication() throws Exception{


        System.out.println("application has started...................");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");            
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");   
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app","D:/SOFTWARES/Apks/autoInsurancelatest.apk");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); 
        System.out.println("Appium SetUp for Android is successful and Appium Driver is launched successfully");
    }

    public static void main(String as[]) throws Exception
    {
        Startup aps = new Startup();

        System.out.println("Starting Server...");

        aps.startAppiumServer();
        System.out.println("Server Started....");
        try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception e){}  

        Startup.startApplication();
        try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception e){}

        System.out.println("Stopping Server");
        aps.stopAppiumServer();
        System.out.println("Server Stopped");
    }

}
```

I found that there is some **port** error when it is creating the new remotewebdriver. I don't find what is missing in the code.

Help me out from this issue. Suggestions and comments are welcome.

***Console log:***

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.45.0',
>   revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35' System info: host:
>   'IMPC1388', ip: '172.16.11.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51' Driver info:
>   driver.version: RemoteWebDriver   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
>     at startup.Startup.startApplication(Startup.java:65)    at
>   startup.Startup.main(Startup.java:79) Caused by:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
>     ... 18 more

Comment: Did you try with selenium 2.44 jar version?

Comment: I have tried with the 2.44 server standalone jar version, but still the same issue is exist.

Comment: then you should use appium driver instead of remote driver. Also can you please share list of files you have imoported?

Comment: Thanks for the effort Helping Hands. I tried with the Appium driver too. But at last writing the Thread.Sleep() function after the Appium server start up method resolved my issue.

Comment: I see..its great that issue solved...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please do the following changes in your code:

1) Take the appium.js from bin directory rather than from lib

2) Add the following

```
command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);
command.addArgument("4724",false);
command.addArgument("--selendroid-port",false);
command.addArgument("8082",false);
```

Also please be sure that you take enough time until appium will start.
Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302110/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-remote-unreachablebrowserexceptio/30354360#30354360) for the details.

If the problem will still appear, could you please copy the command string that your code  build and try to launch it from cmd.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. I have done the above two following changes in my code. But, I got one extra error like

**appium.js: error: argument "-p/--port": Expected one argument. null**

Comment: command.addArgument("--address", false);  
     command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");  
     command.addArgument("--port", false);         
     command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);  
     command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);
     command.addArgument("4724",false);
     command.addArgument("--selendroid-port",false);
     command.addArgument("8082",false);
     DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
     DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
     executor.setExitValue(1);
     executor.execute(command, resultHandler);

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - please provide the command line that this code build. You can just println it before you are going to launch it

Comment: CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
     command.addArgument("/c");
     
     command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node.exe");  
     command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\appium.js");

Comment: If the above code is not the thing you are expected. Please explain me briefly what kind of thing I need to post here.

Comment: Sorry that I don't have enough reputations to talk in chat.

Comment: Eugene I have added the Thread.Sleep() line after the Appium server start up and that resolved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I need some reputations to vote for the answer. Well thanks
Can you look at this another [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594652/how-to-start-the-appium-server-in-ios-machine-through-java-code-from-windows-7#)